# Shadow border on top of a layout

Tags: android

I'm trying to achieve this effect from Google Maps (just the shadow around bottom info window part)

[image]

but what I was able to get so far is this:

[image: this]

The white background is my `RelativeLayout` and I have tried to make the shadow by setting a XML file via `android:background` attribute.

// Drawable XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape 
            android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
        </shape>

    </item>
    <item  android:top="6dp" android:left="0dp" android:bottom="6dp">
       <shape 
            android:shape="rectangle">
        <bitmap android:src="@drawable/drawer_shadow_map"></bitmap>
        </shape>

    </item>
</layer-list>
```

drawer_shadow_map is a 9patch image that looks something like
[image]

Thank you for your help.

Comment: what OS version are you developing for?

Comment: Oops. Sorry, misread the question. Min SDK level 14, Max 19

Comment: Edited - I meant to ask about versions of Android you support

Comment: @TheMetalBeard Yes, I misread it. Answered your question editing my original response.

Comment: The shadow on the example is actually on the map and not on the white rectangle.

Comment: @BlackHatSamurai and how to achieve that?